# Titletoc: split part title in two lines

Tags: table-of-contents, parts, titletoc

I need to split the part title in the `ToC` as follow:

Part I

title of the part

I am using the `titletoc` package. It seems easy with the chapter, but I am not able to figure out how to do it on parts. Any advice?

Comment: Could you show us what you've tried?

Comment: A lot of titletoc examples. But I could not find anything on the internet about doing this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an old example of mine, which I modified to get what you want (and probably some features you don't want, but they're easy to remove):

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[newparttoc,explicit, clearempty]{titlesec}%
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage{fmtcount}
\counterwithin*{chapter}{part}

\def\partname{Part}

\renewcommand\thepart{\NUMBERstring{part}}%
\titleformat{\part}[display]{\bfseries\filcenter}{\huge\partname~\thepart}{20pt}{\Huge #1}[\thispagestyle{empty}]%

\titlecontents{part}[0em]{\large\bfseries\protect\addvspace{25pt}\titlerule\addvspace{1.5ex}}%
{\partname~\thecontentslabel \endgraf}{}%
{\hfill\contentspage}[\addvspace{1ex}\titlerule\addvspace{1ex}]%

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\part{A First Part}
\chapter{Chapter the First}
\section{Section 1.1}
\section{Section 1.2}

\chapter{Chapter the Second}
\section{Section 2.1}
\section{Section 2.2}

\part{Another Part} \label{part-2}

\chapter{Chapter the First}
\section{Section 1.1}
\section{Section 1.2}

\chapter{Chapter the Second}
\section{Section 2.1}
\section{Section 2.2}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Bernard, it worked! I missed the `newparttoc` option!

Comment: You're welcome. I must say finding all the options in the documentation  is not very easy…

Comment: You are right...!